# ship directory of CSVs with R package

Tags: r, csv, package, cran

I have contributed several import functions to [R package](https://github.com/aiorazabala/qmethod), which batch read in CSVs from specifically structured directories (such as [this](https://github.com/maxheld83/keyneson)).

To give users an example, I'd like to ship such a *directory structure* of CSVs *with* the package. 
Since these are *import* functions, it obviously makes no sense to include the data as ready-made `*.rda`.

So I did this:

1. add the directory (with subdirectories) ("keyneson") to `inst/`.
2. document it with a `keyneson.rd` in `man/` as if it were a normal `*.rda` dataset.

`R CMD check` passes without notes/warnings.

Is this ok?
Will CRAN accept this?
Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you read the [data in packages](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages) section of the R extension manual?

Comment: thanks @MrFlick, that was fast.
yes, I have and *directories* are *not* listed as acceptable.

If the directory (with subdirectories) is added to `data/`,  `R CMD check` shouts:

`WARNING Files not of a type allowed in a ‘data’ directory:  ‘keyneson’`

In my case, it is crucial that I ship the directory, with subdirectories, because the function reads data *from* the directory structure.

Comment: `The data subdirectory is for data files... It should not be used for other data files needed by the package, and the convention has grown up to use directory inst/extdata for such files.`

Comment: I see @Dason – so a directory `inst/extdata/keyneson/.../...` would be the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jennifer Bryan](https://github.com/jennybc) suggested on [twitter](https://twitter.com/JennyBryan) that I should use `/inst/extdata` (as @Dason suggested) *and* place an `Rdata` into `/data/`.

She did the same for [her package](https://github.com/jennybc/gapminder), which made it past CRAN.

That's what I did, too, works fine. No complaints from `R CMD check`.

Answer (score 0):

use `devtools::use_data(your_data, overwrite = TRUE)` to save data file to the `data/` folder and it should work.